# Python 3.6 File Decryption with XOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, xor

I've written a bit of code that works great in encrypting a file, however I do not know how to decrypt it. Could someone explain to me how to decry the encrypted file? Thanks.

Code:

```
from itertools import cycle

def xore(data, key):
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(data, cycle(key)))

with open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k.png', 'rb') as encry, open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k_enc.png', 'wb') as decry:
    decry.write(xore(encry.read(), b'anykey'))
```

Comment: To unecrypt a xor encryption, just encrypt it again with the same key: `xore(xore(encry.read(), b'anykey'), b'anykey')` equals original data.

Comment: Thanks. I added with open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k_enc.png', 'rb') as encry, open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k_dec.png', 'wb') as decry:
        xore(xore(encry.read(), b'anykey'), b'anykey') But the outputted file is 0 bytes!

Comment: You misunderstood, you need to apply `xore()` once to encrypted data to decrypt, e.g. `with open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k_enc.png', 'rb') as encry, open('C:\\Users\\saeed\\Desktop\\k_dec.png', 'wb') as decry: decry.write(xore(encry.read(), b'anykey'))`

Comment: Oh, I see! I applied what you said and now the decryption works fine, thanks! However, now there is an error! `xore(decry.write(xore(encry.read(), b'anykey')))
TypeError: xore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'`    I dont know why, as the decryption works just fine @AChampion

Comment: You don't need the outer `xore()`.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To decrypt a xor encryption, you just need to encrypt it again with the same key:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> plain = b'This is a test'
>>> with BytesIO(plain) as f:
...     encrypted = xore(f.read(), b'anykey')
>>> print(encrypted)
b'5\x06\x10\x18E\x10\x12N\x18K\x11\x1c\x12\x1a'
>>> with BytesIO(encrypted) as f:
...     decrypted = xore(f.read(), b'anykey')
>>> print(decrypted)
b'This is a test'
```

Answer (score 2):

The *xor* operation is its own inverse.  If you "encrypt" it a second time with the original key, it will restore the plaintext.